# Web Scraping and http too many requests answer

Tags: c#, http, web-scraping, webclient

When working on a web scraping project, to extract all information i need, i need to make many requests, but the server after about 50 requests it answers with 429 status code that indicates the error "Too many requests", how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you'll either need to slow down the frequency of your requests, or anonymize.  We have a couple of articles on our site that will explain your options if you decide to go the anonymization route:

[How to surf and screen-scrape anonymously](http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2007/03/01/how-to-surf-and-screen-scrape-anonymously/)

[To Anonymize or to Not Anonymize](http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2010/11/11/to-anonymize-or-to-not-anonymize/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using HideMyIP for example, and change your IP every 5 or 10 minutes